# In robotium4.3, how can click on a webelement?

Tags: robotium

In robotium4.3, how can click on a webelement. So far, I can click on a webelement  by locationx and locationy. But it dose not work by webid or other arguments. 
Is there anybody can help me with this problem? TKS!!

Answer (score 0):

There are methods clickOnWebElement in Solo class. There is By class which can be used to find element. For instance:

```
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.className("button"));
```

***By*** implementation you can find [here](https://github.com/jayway/robotium/blob/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/By.java)

Comment: Thank you very much!But the problem still exists.For instance,when I write like this:solo.clickOnWebElement(By.id("t5"));        t5 is a id.  But there is failure,  "junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: WebElement with id: 't5' is not found!   "

Comment: Try with method waitForWebElement (scroll set to true or false) before clicking it.

Comment: Thank you very much! But there are still some problems. Could you give me a simple example about webelement testing ?